# How to properly check if a Logstash pipeline is actually working?

Tags: logstash

I'm using Logstash 7.16.2. I will need to implement readiness/liveness probes to check if necessary Logstash pipelines are actually working: such pipeline are not a necessary component of the system (i.e. if they fail there will not be other errors in unrelated components), but must work and other applications must be stopped if such critical pipelines are not working. I was planning to use the [pipeline stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/node-stats-api.html), but I realized today (DB is offline) that, for example, the `Connection refused` errors in the logs will not produce `failures` in the response. This case is somewhat simple (use both the pipeline stats API and test the db), but I was expecting better stats from the API and I assumed such cases would be covered.

Comment: If you enable persistent queues then the [_node/pipeline API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/node-stats-api.html#pipeline-stats) includes stats about how many events are in the queue. I am not sure how "real time" these are, since I do not use them, but they may allow you to detect a backlog of events.